# How to fix duplicate links problem in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, google-analytics

I have a URL for my categories like this : `example.com/shop/category1`

And this is code in my *web.php* :

```
Route::any('shop/{slug}', 'CategoryController@category')->name('category');
```

And I have many other routes for products, articles Etc.

But when I analyze my website, I have this **shop** in all routes like this :

```
example.com/products/shop
example.com/articles/shop
example.com/shop/shop
```

Other routes works fine, I don't know what is the problem !

Oher routes :

```
Route::any('products', 'ProductController@index')->name('products.index');
Route::get('products/{slug}', 'ProductController@detail')->name('products.detail');

Route::get('articles', 'ArticleController@index');
Route::get('articles/{slug}', 'ArticleController@detail')->name('articles.show');
```

**UPDATE**

screen of routes :

[image: route-scrren-1]

[image: route-screen-2]

[image: route-screen-3]

Comment: can you include a screenshot of php artisan route:list

Comment: @AhmedSaleh Question updated

Comment: @AhmedSaleh That routes are not show in route list, it's showing in analyze systems